# Price difference between the unit price and row total in magento cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout

Hi I am working on magento 1.9.2.4. Have implemented magento porto theme and webkul marketplace extensions. I have 2 currency USD(base currency) and INR(display currency). The product is added in the display currency by the seller. When the buyer adds the product to cart there is s small difference between the unit price and subtotal.

Unit price calculation

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
```

Subtotal Price calculation

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
```

If the product price is Rs.299 the subtotal is being displayed as Rs.299(correct). The Unit price is shown as Rs. 298.69 which may be result of double conversion with truncation.
[image]
I tried with turning the theme as well as well the webkul extensions, the results did not change.

The application can be checked at [link](https://www.geechooin.a2zecart.com)

Comment: Hi There , webkul here still have any issues with the extension please raise a support ticket at http://webkul.uvdesk.com . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found my answer.

Change

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice(), false, false)) ?>
```